# Does "popToViewController" pop all the view controllers in between too?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uikit, poptoviewcontroller

Navigation controllers have a stack of view controllers. So, let us say the stack looks like this:

> [Home, friends, highScores, Add, fullList]

Therefore I am currently on fullList, the top view Controller in the stack. Now if I do:

```
var stack = navigationController!.viewControllers
navigationController?.popToViewController(stack[1] as! UIViewController, animated: true)
```

i.e I pop to the view Controller called friends, does it also pop the view Controllers called highScores and add aswell or leave those and skip down into the stack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Pops view controllers until the specified view controller is at the top of the navigation stack.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:)

Yes.